# Is there a way to dynamically import arrays inside separate files in a directory in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

## What I had tried.

I tried importing every file inside the directory using **require.context**. It did the job and read the files but I am stuck at accessing what's inside the files.

```
function importAll(r) {
    let imports = {};
    r.keys().map((item, index) => { imports[item.replace('./', '')] = r(item); });
    return imports;
}

const imports = importAll(require.context('../questionsdata', false, /\.(js)$/));
```

If I get it correctly, That is the equivalent of me importing every single JS file in the directory.
Each file contains 1 array that is exported and needs to be accessed.

Comment: Have you thought about using `index.js` file with `export` of each file so you can then import all of them at once?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski 
Thank you for your contribution.
My problem is not accessing the data from another component. 
I am trying to import some files in a directory and access an array inside each of them dynamically. 
I do not want to type each import myself to make it possible for more files to be added and rendered automatically.

Comment: How do you add these files? Is it some automated system? Are they generated?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Nope, I feed them manually to the folder.